# Optimizing the sql query that contains CTEs and temptable

Tags: sql-server

I am working on performance optimizing my query.  I have implemented two CTEs as well as created a couple of temporary tables. Finally I am writing a combined query that does the union on CTEs and joins with the temp table. I am sharing the code of where I am defining the CTE's and combined query.I have the following query and would like suggestions on what would be the best practice to improve speed.

```
;with histTbl_CTE 
as (
        select 
            a.companyid,
            a.periodenddate,
            a.pricingdate,
            fp.fiscalYear,
            fp.fiscalQuarter,
            pt.periodtypeId
        from (
            /* determine the cartesian product of periodenddate and pricingdate, assigning 
            a periodenddate to every pricing date that is less than the periodenddate */
                    select 
                            per.companyid, 
                            periodenddate, 
                            pric.pricingdate,
                            datediff(day, pricingdate, periodenddate) as peqdiffdate
                    from  #PeriodTbl per
                    join #PricingTbl pric
                    on (per.companyid = pric.companyid 
                            and per.periodenddate >= pric.pricingdate)
            ) a
        inner join (
                    /*find the different between the pricing date and the period end date */
                    select 
                            per.companyid,
                            periodenddate,
                            min(datediff(day, pricingdate, periodenddate)) minpeqdiffdate
                    from 
                    #PeriodTbl per
                    join #PricingTbl pric
                    on (per.companyid = pric.companyid
                            and per.periodenddate >= pric.pricingdate)
                    group by per.companyid, per.fiscalyear, per.fiscalquarter, periodenddate
            )b
        on a.companyid = b.companyid 
            and a.periodenddate = b.periodenddate
            and a.peqdiffdate = b.minpeqdiffdate
        left join ciqFinPeriod fp on a.companyId = fp.companyId
        left join ciqFinInstance fi on (a.periodenddate = fi.periodenddate
                                                    and fi.financialPeriodId = fp.financialPeriodId)
        left join ciqPeriodType pt on pt.periodTypeId = fp.periodTypeId
        where fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag = 1
            and latestfilingforinstanceflag = 1
            and pt.periodtypeid = 4
        group by a.companyid, a.periodenddate, a.pricingdate, fp.fiscalYear, fp.fiscalQuarter, pt.periodtypeid
        ), 
recentTbl_CTE 
        as (
        --/* use the same methodology from above to find the most recent dates */
        select 
            temp.companyId,
            max(periodenddate) as periodenddate,
            max(peqdate) as pricingDate,
            x.adjFY as fiscalYear,
            x.adjFQ as fiscalQuarter,
            periodTypeId = NULL
        from(
            select
                    a.companyId,
                    a.periodenddate,
                    a.peqdate,
                    b.minpeqdiffdate
            from(
                    select 
                            mc.companyId,
                            mc.pricingDate as periodenddate,
                            peq.pricingDate as peqdate,
                            datediff(day, peq.pricingDate, mc.pricingDate) as peqdiffdate
                    from #MarketTbl mc
                    join #PricingTbl peq
                    on  (mc.companyId = peq.companyId
                            and mc.pricingDate >=peq.pricingDate)
                    group by mc.companyid, mc.pricingDate, peq.pricingDate
                    ) a
            inner join (
                    select 
                            mc.companyId,
                            mc.pricingdate as periodenddate,
                            min(datediff(day, peq.pricingDate, mc.pricingDate)) as minpeqdiffdate
                    from #MarketTbl mc
                    join #PricingTbl peq 
                    on (mc.companyId = peq.companyId
                            and mc.pricingDate >= peq.pricingDate)
                    group by mc.companyid, mc.pricingDate
                    ) b on 
                            a.companyId = b.companyId
                            and a.periodenddate = b.periodenddate
                            and a.peqdiffdate = b.minpeqdiffdate
                    ) temp
        join #futurePer x on x.companyId = temp.companyId
        group by temp.companyid, minpeqdiffdate, adjFY, adjFQ
        having minpeqdiffdate = 0
        )


/* combine all table and join the data*/
select
        combined.companyId,
        combined.periodenddate,
        combined.dataItemName,
        case when combined.dataItemName = 'priceMidUSD' then combined.dataItemidue/exR.currencyRateClose * 1
            when combined.dataItemName = 'sharesOutstanding' then combined.dataItemidue
            when combined.dataItemName = 'marketcaptrend' then combined.dataItemidue
            else combined.dataItemidue/exR.currencyRateClose * 1e6 end as dataItemidue,
        combined.fiscalYear,
        combined.fiscalQuarter,
        combined.periodTypeId,
        ctbl.tickerSymbol,
        ctbl.exchangeName,
        id.dataItemId
from(
        select
            companyId,
            pricingdate,
            periodenddate,
            currencyId,
            dataItemName,
            cast(dataItemidue as float) as dataItemidue,
            fiscalYear,
            fiscalQuarter,
            periodTypeId
        from(
            select 
                            a.companyId,
                            a.pricingdate,
                            c.currencyId, 
                            a.periodenddate,
                            cast(c.priceMid as nvarchar(100)) as priceMidUSD,
                            cast(d.marketCap as nvarchar(100)) as marketCapUSD,
                            cast((d.marketCap/nullif(prevmc.prevmarketCap,0)) - 1 as nvarchar(100)) as marketcaptrend,
                            cast(d.TEV as nvarchar(100)) as TEV,
                            cast(d.sharesOutstanding as nvarchar(100)) as sharesOutstanding,
                            a.fiscalYear,
                            a.fiscalQuarter,
                            a.periodTypeId
            from (
                    select       
                            companyid,
                            periodenddate,
                            pricingdate,
                            fiscalYear,
                            fiscalQuarter,
                            periodtypeId 
                    from histTbl_CTE

                    union all

                    select
                            companyId,
                            periodenddate,
                            pricingDate,
                            fiscalYear,
                            fiscalQuarter,
                            periodTypeId
                    from recentTbl_CTE
                            )a
            join #PricingTbl c
                    on (
                    c.pricingdate = a.pricingDate
                    and c.companyId = a.companyId )
            join #MarketTbl d
                    on (
                    d.companyId = a.companyId
                    and d.pricingDate = a.periodenddate)
            left join (
                    select a.companyId,
                            a.pricingDate,
                            a.prevperiod, 
                            b.marketcap as prevmarketcap
                    from(
                            select 
                                mc.companyid,
                                mc.pricingdate,
                                mc.pricingdate -365 as 'prevperiod'
                            from
                                ciqMarketCap mc
                            where 
                                mc.companyid in (select id from #companyId)
                            ) a
                    inner join (
                            select 
                                mc.companyId,
                                mc.pricingdate,
                                mc.marketcap
                            from #MarketTbl mc 
                            ) b
                            on (a.companyid = b.companyid
                            and a.prevperiod = b.pricingdate)
            ) prevmc
                    on (prevmc.companyid = d.companyid
                            and prevmc.pricingdate = d.pricingdate)

            group by a.companyid, a.periodenddate, a.pricingDate, a.fiscalYear, a.fiscalQuarter, a.periodtypeid, c.currencyId,
                            c.pricemid, d.marketCap, d.TEV, d.sharesOutstanding, prevmc.prevperiod, prevmc.prevmarketcap
            ) c
                    unpivot
                    (dataItemidue for dataItemName in
                            (TEV, marketCapUSD, sharesOutstanding, marketcaptrend, priceMidUSD)
                            ) as unpvt
        ) combined 
join #CompanyInfoTbl ctbl on ctbl.companyId = combined.companyId
```

Comment: Without some idea of the schema, indexing and preferably an execution plan it's going to be very difficult to provide much useful advice.

Comment: I have looked at indexing  the temp tables. I just want to verify the way cte are used and if they are efficient

Comment: A Common Table Expression does not optimize your query, it only makes your query more readable.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for [Stack Exchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  If you agree you can move by clicking flag >> Should be closed.... >> Off-topic because.. >> Belongs on another Stack Exchange site.  Take a look at some of the top reviewed SQL questions to get a feel for how to ask on that site.

Comment: Do i need to dump the result of CTE into temp tables and index the columns. Is that going to help in performance

Comment: More than what Peter sais, at least in the versions of SQL Server I've worked with I have seen queries with CTEs that had horrible efficiency. Rewriting to populate the CTEs to temporary tables made for a huge efficiency boost. In those cases I didn't even have indexes on the temporary tables. Rewrite the query to populate the CTEs in tempprary tables instead, then use those in the final query.

Comment: There are so many things to consider when optimizing a query. Your query with 200 lines is impossible to optimize by itself. You need to have the data structures and an understanding of what this is trying to do. I would also suggest you stop the habit of using a,b,c as alias names. In this post you have repeated the same aliases over and over which makes this user hostile to work with. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: I rewrote the populate CTE to temporary tables but that took more time than the original implementation